# Is Macbook Pro 13 A1502 2015 Retina Screen compatible with Pro 13 A1706 2016 Retina

Tags: macbook-pro-retina

A client just called for a screen replacement enquiry. They have a MacBook Pro 13 A1706 2016 (touch bar) I would assume.
Can't find one at other local repair shops.
I have a Screen from MacBook Pro 13 A1502 Early 2015. Would this screen be compatible with the 2016 one.
I obviously don't have his laptop yet to compare the mobo LCD connector. Kindly HELP

Answer (score 0):

By now the original poster probably has his answer, but for anyone in the future who finds this, no a 2015 display will not work on a 2016. The 2016 redesign has a completely different display assembly and will not work. Various displays are interchangeable between 2012-2015 retina Macbook pros, although it is not always reliable so it is recommended to match a replacement display to your laptop series (Late-2012/Early 2013, Late-2013/Early-2014, Early/Mid-2015, 2016-2017). The 2018-present Macbook Pros have several different displays so it's best to match them exactly. MacBook Air displays stayed the same for longer, with 2013-2017 all being interchangeable. The 2018 Air, of course, follows the redesign of the Pro line and is a retina screen so it is different. hope this helps someone! :)

Comment: Care to explain what is different about it? Is it physically incompatible (only glass panel), i.e. fitment issues? Or is it electronically incompatible, i.e. different connectors, firmware, etc?  I ask because A1706 panels are significantly less expensive and easier to source, making it worth investigating as an alternative to the A1502 panels.